# CString::Find returns wrong value

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I have the following sample code in a Visual C++ MFC application. `CString::Find` is returning the wrong value and I cannot see what the problem is:

```
int     nPos;
CString s, s1;
TCHAR   c1, c2;

s = _T("D)1234");
if (nPos = s.Find(_T("D)")) >= 0)
{
    c1 = s.GetAt(0);
    c2 = s.GetAt(1);
    s1 = s.Mid(nPos + 2);
}
```

The results I get in the debugger are:

```
nPos = 1 (should be 0)
c1 = 'D' (as expected)
c2 = ')' (as expected)
s1 = "234" (instead of "1234" because Find returned the wrong value)
```

This is using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit)
Version 17.0.5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is not with `CString::Find` it is returning the correct value of `0` This can be seen by moving `s.Find` outside of the condition.

```
nPos = s.Find(_T("D)"));
if (nPos >= 0)

Output: nPos = 0 (As expected)
```

The issue is how you have your parentheses, you have:

```
if (nPos = s.Find(_T("D)")) >= 0)
```

Because `>=` has higher priority than `=` this is actually calculated as `nPos = (s.Find(_T("D)") >= 0)`

However for assignment inside the conditional you should have this:

```
if ((nPos = s.Find(_T("D)"))) >= 0)
```

For further reading check out [CWE-783 Operator Precedence Logic Error](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/783.html)

Comment: I've learned the hard way that Operator Precedence assumptions get in the way of productive work.  I try to always put in parentheses, always assuming the reader does not know the C++ Operator Precedence Table by heart.

Comment: Thanks. I really shouldn't be making errors like that.

Comment: @JeffG The issue is rather that C++ invites you to make those mistakes with implicit type conversions all over the place, that happen silently, behind your back.